# Is it possible to improve the facebook comments social plugins

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

I have a wordpress website, and have tried the facebook comments social plugins http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/,
It's working fine, but is it possible to improve?
people can login with their facebook account and can leave comments, but, this activity will only be sent to the user's facebook wall, is it possible to send the comment activity to both the user's wall and my wall?
What i want exactly is, when people comment on my wordpress facebook comment area, it will be shown on my facebook wall
I am grateful to you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The user isn't writing on your Wall.

They are commenting on something/a blog post/the WebPage URL, which they also choose to also publish on their own wall.

A user would need to be friends with you to write on your wall (your own privacy permissions aside).

-- Additional

The thing to note with copying a user comment from your website/the comment plugin to your wall, is that a user might go, "ug how did that get there" and then request its removal or not comment at all/again

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can [subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to the `comment.create` and `comment.remove` events using the `FB.Event.subscribe` function:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function(response) {
        {
            console.log(response.href),      /* Open Graph URL of the Comment Plugin */
            console.log(response.commentID), /* The commentID of the new comment */
            /* Do whatever you want here */
        }
    }
);
```

Then, you can [get the actual comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/) via `https://graph.facebook.com/<comment_id>` and post it to your wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to ditch facebook platform, try [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) or [Livefyre](http://www.livefyre.com/).